# Error while loading shared libraries: foo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pi-3, debian, c++, arm, gcc

I have cross compiled c++ code for raspberry pi.

Below is process I followed:

1) Cloned the [official toolchain from raspberry pi github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools). Set the environment variable of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++` (in `.bashrc` file).

2) Typed this command for generating binary for ARM architecture:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++ ./test.cpp -L. -lfoo -o test
```

3) Binary is successfully generated now. I tried to run the binary with below commands but had no luck with it.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/pi/Downloads/linux-sdk-demo-arm/libfoo.so ./test
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/linux-sdk-demo-arm ./test
```

I even set the environment variable in `.bashrc` file but having no luck.

It gives the below errors respectively:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object './libfoo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.<br/>
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure the `libfoo.so` file is there at the right path but it can not find it. Here's the directory structure:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi  15263 Jan  9 17:23 cp5200api.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1110 Mar  6 12:17 dtype.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 152751 Mar  9 13:43 libfoo.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi    512 Mar 12 08:42 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1285 Mar  8 20:13 notplugged
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1285 Mar  8 20:13 plugged
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  13228 Mar 12 08:42 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   2204 Mar  6 15:22 test.cpp
```

Comment: `foo.so` looks suspicious... Normally libraries are called `libfoo.so` under linux

Comment: For naming convention i have written it as foo.so but in real its libfoo.so. Edited the question

Answer (score 2):

One thing that doesn't look right is that your `LD_PRELOAD` contains an absolute path, while the error message complains about a relative path, `./libfoo.so`. Make sure you use the absolute path in `LD_PRELOAD`.

If you're actually using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you should check whether you've built `test` against `libfoo.so`, and not something else. Run

```
ldd ./test
```

and check out the library name that your program expects. Chances are, it corresponds to its SONAME which you can find with

```
objdump -p libfoo.so | grep SONAME
```

SONAME is typically slightly different, e.g. `libfoo.so.0`, and renaming (or symlinking) your library to that name will help.

### Edit

Since the above doesn't seem to help, here's one more thing I would try. Add the full path containing `libfoo.so` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`. Then run

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Check the output for lines concerning `libfoo.so`, maybe there will be something useful.

Alternatively, try copying `libfoo.so` to one of the standard library locations, like `/usr/local/lib`, and again, run `sudo ldconfig -v`.

Comment: ldd ./test does show that libfoo.so does not found but i am sure that library is in the current directory. Also i tried everything including running executable,LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH with full path but having no luck

Comment: objdump -p libfoo.so | grep libfoo outputs libfoo.so: file format elf32-littlearm

Comment: @Aniket SONAME is not a placeholder for libfoo, it's an [actual parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) of a shared library in Linux. You should therefore run `grep SONAME`, and make sure to make it uppercase.

Comment: it outputs nothing @grigoryev

Comment: @Aniket Thanks for checking. Can you also try the things I edited into the answer?

Comment: Yes, tried the same. Also tried with arm-linux-gnuhf directory as well. But having no luck

Comment: This answer is on the right track. It's odd that `libfoo.so` lacks a soname, but that isn't mandatory. Try more **ldd** commands including with the library search path i.e.: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/linux-sdk-demo-arm ldd ./test` and also run `ldd libfoo.so`. Ideally one of these commands will reveal a missing dependency (`=> not found`), mismatching libc version (compared to `ldd --version`) or the wrong loader (something other than /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3).

Answer (score 0):

Does libfoo is compiled as ARM library (or) x86 library. You can check and confirm this using file utility

```
file <absolute/relate_path_to_libfoo_folder>/libfoo.so
```

The above command should provide the architecture as ARM instead if you see it as i386 (or) i686 then the library is compiled for x86 architecture which can't be used on the Pi. You need to compile the library using the same cross toolchain first and then use it to link to your test application.

Comment: The poster (and also the error messages in his post) show that the file cannot be found. So it's not a problem with a different architecture at this point...

Comment: According to the poster description the file is present in the directory so I thought of this possibility.

Comment: It is compiled for ARM. Here is the output of `file libfoo.so`
`libCP5200.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`

Comment: Also output of `file ./test`     `./test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=af019abeb87723b522d440f1c44ba2f85cd0356a, not stripped`